# Scrapy - TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, typeerror

While I try to gather a list of URL from a website and put them to combine with a base URL, then continue it inside the page.

Once combine and will crawl those Url 1 by 1 then crawl the details of it.
The Layer is like `MainPage` > `Categories` > `List of Company` > `Details of each company` (data I want)

it's return TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str.
Below is my code for Scrapy Spider

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import Rule
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
# from urllib.parse import urljoin


class ZomatoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'zomato'
    allowed_domain = ['foodbizmalaysia.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.foodbizmalaysia.com/category/3/bakery-pastry-supplies?classid=DS-B42850']
    headers = {
        "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
        "cookie": "dnetsid=5kegaefgfpb0efhf3idfxn30; afrvt=14846924c9bb4e87b5576addf94f8cc4; _ga=GA1.2.1937980614.1603360774; _gid=GA1.2.1358979332.1603360774"
    }


    def parse(self, response):
        url = "http://www.foodbizmalaysia.com/"

        yield scrapy.Request(url, 
            callback=self.parse_api, 
            headers=self.headers)
        


    def parse_api(self, response):
        base_url = 'http://www.foodbizmalaysia.com'
        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = sel.xpath('/html')
                
        for data in sites:
            categories = data.xpath('//div[@class="post_content"]/a[contains(@href, "category")]/@href').extract()
            category_url = base_url + categories

            request = scrapy.Request(
                category_url, 
                callback=self.parse_restaurant_company, 
                headers=self.headers
            ) 

            yield request


    def parse_restaurant_company(self, response):
        base_url = 'http://www.foodbizmalaysia.com'
        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = sel.xpath('/html')

        for data in sites:
            company = data.xpath('//a[contains(@id, "ContentPlaceHolder1_dgrdCompany_Hyperlink4_")]/@href').extract_first()
            company_url = base_url + company
            # for i in company:
            #     yield response.urljoin(
            #         'http://www.foodbizmalaysia.com', i[1:],
            #         callback=self.parse_company_details)

        request = scrapy.Request(
                company_url,
                callback=self.parse_company_details, 
                headers=self.headers

        )
        yield request

    def parse_company_details(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = sel.xpath('/html')

        yield {
            'name' : sites.xpath('//span[@class="coprofileh3"]/text()').get()
        }
```

As below is the log after I scrapy runspider:

```
2020-10-23 10:58:50 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.4.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
2020-10-23 10:58:50 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.5.0.0, libxml2 2.9.10, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 18.9.0, Python 3.8.6 (default, Sep 25 2020, 09:36:53) - [GCC 10.2.0], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020), cryptography 2.8, Platform Linux-5.5.0-kali2-amd64-x86_64-with-glibc2.29
2020-10-23 10:58:50 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.epollreactor.EPollReactor
2020-10-23 10:58:50 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'SPIDER_LOADER_WARN_ONLY': True}
2020-10-23 10:58:50 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 97316bde34a4b21d
2020-10-23 10:58:50 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2020-10-23 10:58:50 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2020-10-23 10:58:50 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2020-10-23 10:58:50 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2020-10-23 10:58:50 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-10-23 10:58:50 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-10-23 10:58:50 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6024
2020-10-23 10:58:52 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.foodbizmalaysia.com/category/3/bakery-pastry-supplies?classid=DS-B42850> (referer: None)
2020-10-23 10:58:54 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.foodbizmalaysia.com/> (referer: http://www.foodbizmalaysia.com/category/3/bakery-pastry-supplies?classid=DS-B42850)
2020-10-23 10:58:54 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://www.foodbizmalaysia.com/> (referer: http://www.foodbizmalaysia.com/category/3/bakery-pastry-supplies?classid=DS-B42850)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/limjack4511/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 120, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "/home/limjack4511/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/utils/python.py", line 353, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "/home/limjack4511/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/utils/python.py", line 353, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "/home/limjack4511/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 62, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "/home/limjack4511/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "/home/limjack4511/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 62, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "/home/limjack4511/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/referer.py", line 340, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "/home/limjack4511/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 62, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "/home/limjack4511/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/home/limjack4511/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 62, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "/home/limjack4511/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/home/limjack4511/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 62, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "/home/limjack4511/Dev/0temp/zomato.py", line 34, in parse_api
    category_url = base_url + categories
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
2020-10-23 10:58:54 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-10-23 10:58:54 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 752,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 34411,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 3.888395,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 23, 2, 58, 54, 321201),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'memusage/max': 53633024,
 'memusage/startup': 53633024,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'spider_exceptions/TypeError': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 23, 2, 58, 50, 432806)}
2020-10-23 10:58:54 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: Could you include the full traceback?

Comment: it also looks like `yield response.urljoin('http://www.foodbizmalaysia.com', i[1:],callback=self.parse_company_details)` could giving you a problem; specifically `i[1:]`

Comment: Hi @Ironkey now I try to remove the i[1:] and as below:

Comment: @J9cki11er Please edit your question and add the additional information.

Comment: @renatodvc have updated

Comment: @J9cki11er I meant edit the question and add the data there, not in the comments as you did (too late to delete the comments now, but you should aggregate the data of your problem in the question anyway). Since we are at it, please include your execution log in the question as well.

Comment: @renatodvc have added the execution log, may have a looks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems in your code that makes it seems **like the code you are executing is NOT the same you posted**. For example, this is your `parse_api` method (copied and pasted):

```
def parse_api(self, response):
    base_url = 'http://www.foodbizmalaysia.com'
    sel = Selector(response)
    sites = sel.xpath('/html')
            
    for data in sites:
        categories = data.xpath('//div[@class="post_content"]/a[contains(@href, "category")]/@href').extract()


        request = scrapy.Request(
            category_url, 
            callback=self.parse_restaurant_company, 
            headers=self.headers
        ) 
        yield request
```

That would raise a `NameError` as `category_url` isn't defined anywhere. That's not the only inconsistency, here is a piece of your execution log:

```
  File "/home/limjack4511/Dev/0temp/zomato.py", line 33, in parse_api
    category_url = base_url + categories
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
```

It's telling me that in the method `parse_api` this line is returning an error:         `category_url = base_url + categories`, but **this line doesn't exist in this method** (not in the one you posted at least), you have that same line, but inside another method, called `parse_restaurant_company`.

---

The error is telling you that you are trying to concatenate a string with a list, which means that from `base_url` and `categories` one is a string and another is a list. I can't tell which is which because I can't trust the code you posted.

---

### Edit:

Now with the full code I can tell you here is the problem: (`parse_api` method)

```
    for data in sites:
        categories = data.xpath('//div[@class="post_content"]/a[contains(@href, "category")]/@href').extract()
        category_url = base_url + categories
```

You are calling `.extract()` when defining categories. The extract method returns a list not a string. Replace it with `.get()` or `.extract_first()`

**On another note:** You probably want to use `data.xpath('.//div[...` instead of `data.xpath('//div[...`, because the first case will look for that XPath inside the `data` node. Without the `.` it will look for the XPath in the whole document, ignoring the context already established by the `data` var.

Comment: I have reposted the whole code and the execution log to my question may have a look.

Comment: @J9cki11er Just edited my answer, let me know if it helped.

Comment: Hi @renatodvc, I have tried your method which using extract_first(), it manages to crawl the data out. But currently, it's only crawling 1 data from homepage instead of go thru all the link of href. any idea how can the spider crawl and go thru all the href that I crawled?

Comment: @J9cki11er I don't really understand what you are trying to to there. You are iterating over `sites`, but that variable will return only **ONE selector** (as it selects `//html`), so it doesn't iterate at all. Maybe you should be iterating over what you are defining as `categories`? In that case you need to define it outside the loop and use `.extract()` again (as you will need a list).